# How to set a maximum message character limit in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a server and i don't want users to send long messages at all. So here is my current version of code:

````
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return;
  let sChannel = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === "guard-log");
  if(!sChannel) return
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${message.author.username} tarafından gönderilen bir mesaj silindi`)
      .setDescription(`${message.content}`)
      .setTimestamp() //.toLowerCase.replace(/ /g, '').trim() 
    if(message.length > 100){ return message.delete()
  message.channel.send(`${message.author.nickname} spam is disabled!`).then(message => message.delete(10000))}
      sChannel.send(embed)
});```
````

Comment: ...ok? Is something going wrong? What do you need help with exactly? Just showing your code isn't enough.

Comment: it doesn't work. everyone can send messages longer than stated number. it logs the channel but it doesn't delete message. also i change code a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message` is the entire [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object. You need to be measuring the length of the *[`content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content)* property of the `message` object.

```js
if (message.content.length < 100) return message.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to check `message.content.length`

```
if (message.content.length > 100) return message.delete()
```